# Local taskbar visible during remote desktop fullscreen

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, taskbar, always-on-top

When I do remote desktop fullscreen connection on Windows 10 local host to Windows 7 remote host, the local task bar will not get covered by the RDP window as it used to be. It remains visible on top and the only help is to set the local taskbar to auto-hide. It overlays and hides the remote taskbar.

It had started to happen after some update, not sure which one, perhaps the Creators update.

I use shortcut on desktop, tried various settings but without any success.

How can I make the local taskbar hidden behind the RDP fullscreen window? (and not visible on top of the remote desktop fullscreen window rendering the remote taskbar unavailable?)

[image: Local taskbar on top of the remote one]

Comment: Does [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/104465/611876) help? It seems pretty similiar to your issue.

Comment: @TimmyJim not at all. I have RDP fullscreen, so I do not have the linked issue at all. Only taskbar is on top and not behind RDP window, that is the problem.

Comment: With remote working I fight this every single day. At times I move my local taskbar around to avoid the conflict but it's still annoying.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I have figured it out today using a hint from [this discussion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e89f6f84-067e-45c2-ab00-e3d45ebe8a33/full-screen-rdp-shows-local-taskbar-in-foreground?forum=win10itprogeneral).

> *"Thanks Tony, that means **a program has raised the MustBeSeen system
>   flag**.  Typically this is a program that needs your attention, like
>   antivirus or backup program that has some message it's waiting to tell
>   you.  It is almost always a program icon near the clock in the
>   notification area.  Once you clear the MustBeSeen flag by addressing
>   the program, the taskbar will hide again.*
>
> *As a best practice suggestion, hit Ctrl+Shift+Escape and **disable
>   anything on the Startup tab you don't need autorunning**.  That limits
>   how many things load there, and lessens how many programs can raise
>   the MustBeSeen flag."*
>
> There must have been something in the Windows 10 Anniversary Update
>   that's changed the way how the taskbar overlays work and so seems to
>   be causing it.

So I have closed all my apps running in the background with notification icon and the problem went away.

[Here is a link to the quoted answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/auto-hide-task-bar/362df0e4-e65a-43a8-ab83-fefaedffb656).

Comment: So this bug is not going to be fixed? I use RDP often and this often happens, making fullscreen work on the remote computer very annoying.

Comment: This is a horrible mis-feature of windows. I am going to switch to using Linux as my host operating system and then remote into windows and VMs, because Microsoft can't make a useable home base for me in windows. I can't stop stupid programs from raising this flag.

Comment: I think it is "by design feature" that got into windows as they try to make one Windows for PCs, tablets and phones. Unfortunately it makes the desktop OS less usable.

Comment: It was Outlook that was causing this problem for me! Got a feeling they have a lot of temps working at MS nowadays :-D

Comment: In my case, it was that the battery was running low + some apps stopped working, and consequently the Windows Security Center had "Actions Recommended."

Comment: Anyone knows some tool which would be able to identify which app actually set this flag?

Comment: Seems like this doesn't work here. I closed all applications which were either present in the notification area or in the task bar itself. Plus I read and removed all the messages shown in the Windows Action Center. Still doesn't want to show me the task bar of the remote system. Probably anyone got a clue?

Comment: This is not a bug!  This is a feature, and an awesome one at that!  Now I can have local Skype running on one monitor with my local taskbar on that monitor, and the RDP taskbar on the other monitor!!!

Answer (score 88):

Try restarting explorer.exe process as mentioned in [fixing remote desktop taskbar](http://how-i-fixed-it.blogspot.com/2017/01/windows-remote-desktop-local-taskbar.html)

Comment: Restarting it tends to only fix the problem for an hour or so in my case, or until the MustBeSeen flag is triggered again.

Comment: Better use the link to the superuser q&a than to that blog - http://superuser.com/questions/495871/taskbar-disappears-over-remote-desktop-connection-when-outside-local-network

Comment: @Vojtěch Dohnal, that question is not for the same issue.

Comment: @MGranja It is not but the blog the answerer quotes quotes one answer to that question.

Comment: life saver..i have struggled with this issue for so long and m glad i looked here

Comment: Restarting explorer.exe worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have Snagit on my home computer. If I open it (or it's a startup program), the taskbar of my home computer overlaps the taskbar of my remote computer. If I close Snagit on my home computer side, viola! Problem solved. Find the program running on the non-remote computer that is forcing its way into the foreground, then, "FINISH HIM!"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and decided to try the remove the "I need to be seen" task. But I just right clicked on the icons and then clicked on "remove from taskbar" I kept the ones that I know have been there before the problem and removed the others. After I did that I could see my remote desktop taskbar!

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10 to hide the local taskbar in the [Microsoft Store Remote Desktop](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9WZDNCRFJ3PS?hl=en-us&gl=US), you can follow these steps on **local host**:

**Option 1.** Use Local Group Policy Editor

1. Open the Local Group Policy Editor as administrator by typing *gpedit.msc* in Windows taskbar search box, locate *gpedit.msc* and click on *Run as administrator*.
2. Navigate to: *Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Edge UI*.
3. In the right pane, double-click the on *Allow edge swipe* policy.
4. To hide the local taskbar, select the *Disabled* option. Click *Apply* and then *OK*.

[image: gpedit.msc window]

**Option 2.** Use Windows Registry Editor

1. Open the Windows Registry Editor as administrator by typing *regedit* in Windows taskbar search box, locate *Registry Editor* and click on *Run as administrator*.
2. Navigate to the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EdgeUI
```

3. If the *EdgeUI* key does not exist, you may need to create it. Right-click on the Windows key, choose New, and then select Key. Name the new key as *EdgeUI*.
4. Inside the *EdgeUI* key, create a new DWORD (32-bit) value. Right-click on the right side, choose New, and then select DWORD (32-bit) Value. Name it *AllowEdgeSwipe*.
5. Double-click on *AllowEdgeSwipe* and set its value to 0.

Make sure to restart the Microsoft Remote Desktop app back in to see the changes take effect.

Comment: I'm not sure why you were down voted but this (I used option 2) works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find the *offending* task (perhaps is my remote utility that I cannot disable not to lose the connection). As a workaround I was able to move the overlapping bar to the right side of the screen allowing me to see the remote bottom bar.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution on my Win10 machine where this happens regularly:

- Right click on task bar
- Choose Taskbar settings
- Enable and disable the setting to show/not show task bar on multiple screens

Now it should work as expected.